# Switching from FireFoxDriver to ChromeDriver cause some element loading errors (Selenium)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a selenium project and until now I used FireFoxDriver, but now I tried to use ChromeDriver (which is X100 faster) and I get allot of fails in my tests with the error "element not visible" or "Element is not currently intractable and may not be manipulated"

Is there a need for more wait.until? Why is this?

Comment: You should always wait until elements are usable before trying to interact with them (well, at least for the first element if the page is static). It makes dealing with slight browser differences across different platforms and versions and hardware specs vastly easier. That's the nature of software. The crucial thing is to avoid hard-coding waits, which will kill test performance.

Comment: how can I avoid hard-coded waits? all of my waits looks like: `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("invoice_country")))`
'

Comment: @AndrewRegan maybe  I can put everything in the configuration file

Comment: I mean it's ideal to use the built-in wait methods that poll (often!) up to a certain timeout - not 'wait 2 secs' etc.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium needs elements to be visible/exist in the DOM in order to interact with them. As you said, Chrome is faster than FireFox, so the `WebDriver` is trying to interact with the DOM before when elements are not yet visible/exist.

Explicit wait

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated());
```

And implicit wait

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Should solve your problem.

Comment: im using: `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("invoice_country")))` and `    val wait: WebDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120)
`

Comment: You should use wait.until where ever you get element is not visible exception, for the element you want to interact with, not one general element.